# E11000 duplicate key error collection when insterting data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

this is my schema for Mongodb:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { MinioBucket } from '../../../common/enums';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema({ versionKey: false, timestamps: true })
export class Column extends Document {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  tableCol: string;
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  sheetCol: string;
}
const ColumnSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Column);

@Schema({ versionKey: false, timestamps: true })
export class Col extends Document {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true, unique: true })
  public readonly provider!: string;

  @Prop({ type: [ColumnSchema] })
  cols: Column[];
}

const ColSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Col);

ColSchema.index({ provider: 1 });
export { ColSchema };
```

in database I saved:
{
provider: "abc",
columns: [
{"tableCol": "name"
"sheetCol": "Name"}
]
}

Now when I want to add another provider, but with the same columns name I recieve the error:
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] E11000 duplicate key error collection: xxx.columns index: columns.tableCol_1 dup key: { columns.tableCol: "name" }
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: xxx.columns index: columns.tableCol_1 dup key: { columns.tableCol: "name" }

Data I want to add:
{
provider: "cde",
columns: [
{"tableCol": "name"
"sheetCol": "Name"}
]
}

I tried to put {unique: false}, and I found on internet about {spars: true}, but it didn't help

And I cannot drop the Index, I need to have both data in database

Comment: I don't think I understand the comment that you can't drop the index. If the index has a unique constraint applied to it that you don't want, then you will have to drop it

Answer (score 0):

If you drop the index – it will **not** drop data in the database.

You need to create a [compound index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-compound/) for both `provider` and `cols.tableCol` fields.

To do so, first, create a compound idex:

```js
ColSchema.index({ provider: 1, 'cols.tableCol': 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Then, drop the old index.

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering a MongoDB error related to a null index, it might be due to changes in your schema during development. This issue often arises when an index, such as "name_1," is created automatically by MongoDB based on your initial schema, and subsequent changes to the schema result in the creation of a null index value.

Understanding the Issue, When MongoDB throws an error with details like:

```
keyPattern: { name: 1 },
keyValue: { name: null },
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
```

It indicates the presence of a null index value, specifically in the "name_1" index. This occurs when a field initially named "name" in your schema is later modified to something else, like "username," resulting in both "name" and "username" indexes.

To resolve this error, you have two options:

1. Using MongoDB Compass:

Open MongoDB Compass and connect to your database.

[MongoDB Compass User Interface][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wuv2.png

Navigate to your desired collection (e.g., "users" or "blog").
Click on the "Indexes" tab.
Identify the problematic index causing the error, and delete it.
Alternatively, delete all indexes if you are uncertain about the specific index causing the issue.

2. Using mongosh (MongoDB Shell):

Open your terminal or command prompt.
Connect to your MongoDB server using mongosh, replacing <connection_string> with your actual connection string.

```
mongosh <connection_string>
```

Switch to the relevant database using the use command, replacing <database_name> with your actual database name.

```
 use <database_name>
```

View existing indexes for the collection to identify the problematic index.

```
db.<collection_name>.getIndexes()
```

Delete the identified index using the dropIndex command.

If uncertain, remove all indexes for the collection.

```
db.<collection_name>.dropIndexes()
```

Verify that the index has been successfully removed.

```
db.<collection_name>.getIndexes()
```

Exit the MongoDB Shell.

exit

By following these steps, you should successfully resolve the MongoDB null index issue. Ensure to replace placeholders like <database_name>, <collection_name>, and <index_name> with your actual database, collection, and index names.